# What does this mean "PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer" and "PDO does not provide a database abstraction"?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am new to PHP and decided to start learning PDO but one thing that is confusing me a lot that is:
**PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer**
and
**PDO does not provide a database abstraction**

What does it means ?

[Reference link](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)

Can anyone tell ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: This is explained in the second paragraph in your link...

Comment: I think the page to which your link refers explains it very well. You can use the same PHP functions when using PDO for different database, but you might need to adapt your SQL to the database you're using.

Comment: @KIKO-I got your first point but your second point is bit confusing can you provide a complete answer and i will mark it useful !!!

Comment: I would suggest to continue learning PDO, and this will become very clear to you. SQL written for, say a MySQL database, does, for example, not always work on a SQLite database. So you need to change the SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDO provides a **data-access** abstraction layer: PDO can abstract the "database driver" (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL etc...).

PDO does not provide a **database abstraction:** PDO cannot abstract SQL statements.

**Example**

This SQL works with MySQL but not with PostgreSQL.

```
// MySQL connection
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, $options);

$sql = "REPLACE INTO blog (uuid, title) VALUES (:uuid, :title)";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(['uuid' => '1234', 'title' => 'test']);

// PostgreSQL connection
$pdo2 = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, $options);

// This should fail
$pdo2->prepare($sql)->execute(['uuid' => '1234', 'title' => 'test']);
```

PS: PDO does not provide a "real" data-access abstraction layer.

For example the PDO object has a `lastInsertId()` function. For SQLite and MySQL you can just call it as such:

```
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

However, PostgreSQL requires an explicit sequence identifier. By default this follows the format `<tablename>_<idField>_seq`, so we might specifiy as this:

```
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId('articles_id_seq');
```

Luckily the parameter gets ignored by SQLite and MySQL, so we can just specify it all the time.

Comment: Can you do one example for me ?

Comment: Ok it means the database functions are same but SQL statements may differ in different databases i-e MySQL has different SQL statements when creating new Table as compare to Oracle database. You mean we have to manually handle the SQL statements and PDO does not handles it manually, its upon the programmer. Is i am correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, *data-access abstraction* refers to how PDO interacts on your behalf with a given *database*. Generally speaking, all the nitty-gritty details such as connection specific properties, security, transactions etc. are implemented for you in a standard manner. All you need to do is learn how PDO implements these and then you can start using MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, Postgres.

That being said, it doesn't write the actual SQL/DML for you. You still need to physically type that in. Which bring us to the 2nd point, *database abstraction*. This refers to hiding the low-level SQL/DML needed to perform queries. If you've ever worked with an ORM then you'll be familiar with this concept. Instead of writing

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ...'
```

you'd write

```
$db->get(Person, $id)
```

In summary, with PDO you get:

- connections, security, error handling, and other *data access abstractions*

You don't get:

- SQL/DML written behind the scenes for you like you would with an ORM

Take a peek at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo for a better understanding.

Comment: Ok it means the database functions are same but SQL statements may differ in different databases i-e MySQL has different SQL statements when creating new Table as compare to Oracle database. You mean we have to manually handle the SQL statements and PDO does not handles it manually, its upon the programmer. Is i am correct ?

Comment: _Ok it means the database functions are same..._. No, they are not the same; but PDO makes them consistent.

Comment: I means all the PDO functions for the databases are same i-e PDO->exec() but the SQL statements may different for databases. Is i am right ?

Comment: Yes, you got it.